# Unable to receive offline messages when a new client is initialized with same client id in MQTTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mqtt

Currently, a session does not seem to be retained when an MQTTClient object is **reinitialized** with the same client id and then connected to the broker.

Consider the following code:

```
//Just a tiny wrapper around MQTTClient for custom methods
@property (nonatomic, strong) RAMQTTClient *client;

@implementation MQTTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //The selector gets called whenever a new message is received
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveMessage:) name:@"didReceiveMessage" object:nil];

    //Initialises an MQTT client with QOS=1 and cleanSession=NO
    _client = [[RAMQTTClient alloc]initWithId:@"client-1"];
}

-(void)didReceiveMessage:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *data = (NSString *)notification.object;
    NSLog(@"Received: %@", data);
}

// Use a switch action to subscribe and disconnect
- (IBAction)switchUpdated:(id)sender {
    BOOL on = [sender isOn];
    if (on) {
        [_client listenToTopic:@"a~1"];
    } else {
        [_client disconnect];
    }
}

@end
```

As long as the `_client` object is not destroyed, disconnecting and reconnecting does retrieve the offline messages sent in that interval. However if the client gets reinitialised and then starts to listen, I don't get any of the offline messages.

The following is the implementation of `RAMQTTClient`:

```
typedef void (^ConnectionCompletionHandler)(MQTTConnectionReturnCode code);

@interface RAMQTTClient()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MQTTClient *client;
@property (nonatomic) MQTTConnectionReturnCode connectionCode;
@end

@implementation RAMQTTClient

-(instancetype)initWithId:(NSString*)id {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _client = [[MQTTClient alloc]initWithClientId:id cleanSession:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isRunning {
    return _client.connected;
}

-(NSString *)id {
    return _client.clientID;
}

-(void)connectWithCompletionHandler:(ConnectionCompletionHandler)handler {
    if (!_client.connected) {
        [_client connectToHost:@"localhost" completionHandler:handler];
    }
}

-(void)listenToTopic:(NSString *)topic {
    ConnectionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(MQTTConnectionReturnCode code) {
        NSLog(@"RAMQTTClient: %@ connected", _client.clientID);
        _connectionCode = code;
        if (code == ConnectionAccepted) {
            [_client subscribe:topic withQos:AtLeastOnce completionHandler:^(NSArray *grantedQos) {
                NSLog(@"RAMQTTClient: Listening to %@", topic);
                [_client setMessageHandler:^(MQTTMessage *message) {
                    NSLog(@"Message => %@",message.payloadString);
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"didReceiveMessage"
                                                                       object:message.payloadString];
                }];
            }];
        }
    };
    [self connectWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

-(void)disconnect {
    if (_client.connected) {
        [_client disconnectWithCompletionHandler:^(NSUInteger code) {
            NSLog(@"RAMQTTClient: %@ Disconnected with code %u", _client.clientID, code);
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Have any of you faced this sort of issue before? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I've figured it out. The problem was setting a message handler after subscribing to a topic. Since offline messages arrive instantly when you subscribe, the client is unable to wait or set the message handler before receiving them. As a result, even though the messages arrive, they aren't sent to the handler. Setting the message handler before subscribing to the channel solves this.

```
[_client setMessageHandler:^(MQTTMessage *message) {
    NSLog(@"Message => %@",message.payloadString);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"didReceiveMessage"
                                                       object:message.payloadString];
}];
[_client subscribe:topic withQos:AtLeastOnce completionHandler:^(NSArray *grantedQos) {
            NSLog(@"RAMQTTClient: Listening to %@", topic);
}];
```

Comment: whenever i start a new session with same topic ,i am getting the last message in queue as default.How can i discard that